# Gremlin Java replace old vertex properties with new property

Tags: gremlin

I am trying to use gremlin java to replace some vertex's property like this:
`graph.V(1).properties().drop().property("foo", "bar").iterate()`

However, this only remove property but doesn't add new property.
I think iterate should probably be immediately after drop, but I am connecting to remote graph db so I wish to reduce query count.
Hope there is some way to achieve this:

`graph.V(1).properties().drop().property("foo", "bar")
.V(2).properties().drop().property("foo", "bar").....iterate()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely do that, check out the live example: https://gremlify.com/27

You can select the vertex and see it's properties, or run `g.V().valueMap(true)` and afterwards:

```
g.V().sideEffect(properties ().drop()).property ("foo", "boo");
```

To see the new properties applied to it.

(For simplicity, I assumed a single vertex on the graph but this applies for any vertex).

Comment: This is exactly what i want!

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @gremlify is correct. And alternatively you can use .union() command also.

```
g.V().union(
    properties().drop(),
    property('foo', 'boo')
);
```

Comment: SideEffect is in fact supported in Neptune. In line code is not supported.

Comment: Oh then I might need to edit the answer. Most of the time used only Java driver and inline code. Thanks

Comment: Is g.V('id').property (single,"foo", "boo")  not enough to replace an existing property, why does the need to drop all properties arise ?